# Que poster automatiquement dans le salon de clavardage ? What feeds should we have in chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

Une armée de robots poste automatiquement sur le [salon de clavardage principal du site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette) des liens vers les nouvelles questions sur le site ainsi que sur d'autres sites proches. Jusqu'à maintenant, il y avait les questions :

- du site principal ;
- du site méta ;
- de [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) avec l'étiquette [french](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/tags/french).

Je viens de rajouter les questions sur [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) avec l'étiquette [french](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/french), et sur [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/), [Skeptics](https://history.stackexchange.com/) et [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) avec des étiquettes concernant des régions (au moins partiellement) francophones.

Est-ce que c'est trop ? Est-ce que vous en voulez d'autres ? (Notez que l'avalanche de messages de ce soir était un évènement exceptionnel : quand on met en place un robot, la première chose qu'il fait est d'aller chercher des vieux messages à poster. Une fois le robot en place, il ne poste que des liens vers les nouvelles questions.)

Notez que vous pouvez ignorer chaque robot sélectivement, ce qui signifie que les messages de ce robot vous seront cachés (comme pour un utilisateur réel). Cliquez sur son nom ou son icône à gauche de ses messages, puis sur “ignore this user (everywhere)”. Ou bien rendez-vous sur la [liste des robots](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1098/chez-cosette?tab=feeds) et suivez le lien vers le profil de l'utilisateur-robot puis cliquez sur “ignore this user”.

---

An army of bots automatically posts links to new questions on the site and related sites to the [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette). Until now, there were questions from the main and meta sites, and from [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) tagged [french](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/tags/french).

I've just added questions from [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) tagged [french](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/french), and from [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/), [Skeptics](https://history.stackexchange.com/) and [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) with tags indicating (partially) French-speaking regions.

Is this too much? Do you want others? (Note that there was a rush of incoming messages immediately after setting up the feed, because it goes looking for old messages. That won't happen again, only links to new questions will be posted from now on.)

Note that you can ignore each robot selectively, meaning that you won't see its messages. Click on “ignore this user” in the pop-up that appears when you click its name in chat, or on the robot user's profile page. You can find a handy list of robots that flood the site on the [feeds list](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1098/chez-cosette?tab=feeds).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a person who actually use the chat, I would rather set up feeds so that only meta posts and maybe selected posts from a few other sites are shown automatically.

Dumping posts from the main site into the chatroom achieves little except for adding clutter and useless redundancy. In any case it's easy to “onebox” a post when needed (just paste its url), and moreover it seems to me that these posts are detrimental to the chat's general activity and legibility.

Comment: « *it's easy to “onebox”* » : Il suffit de poster l'URL de la question, pour ceux qui se demanderaient.

Comment: Entièrement d'accord avec Stéphane G. Je ne sais pas où intervenir avec  cette avalanche de messages. Mettre tous les messages de meta me semble un peu trop aussi. Juste attirer l'attention vers ceux qui sont nécessaires pour la discussion me parait suffisant.  The chatroom is very difficult to use with all these posts. Even all meta posts seem a bit too much to me, except when useful of course.

Comment: I used to like the chat feeds because they were a way to be automatically notified of new questions. This was before the front page and `/questions` had live updates, so for me the chat feeds have lost most of their use. I now favor feeding only things that people would otherwise miss, like `[french]`-tagged posts on [linguistics.se] and [english.se], and perhaps also meta and bountied questions.

Comment: With 5 upvotes, I think we have as broad agreement as it gets on Meta.French. I've removed the feed for main site questions (Ling.SE, ELU, Meta.Fr and bounties are still fed).

Answer (score 2):

Are newly offered bounties an option?

I feel like [two of](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/46/1514) [them](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2625/1514) went largely unnoticed, that wouldn't be much additional traffic, and bounties do deserve discussion, even more with [Improving bounty messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154871/improving-bounty-messages) being necessary.

Comment: Good idea. It's done (assuming I set things up correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think updates from things like "travel in French-speaking regions" is too noisy.  It should just be limited to updates from the main and meta sites.

Comment: J'ai retiré les feeds de [travel.se], [history.se] et [skeptics.se], mais laissé ceux de [english.se] et [linguistics.se] qui parlent de langue (ça ne fait même pas un message par mois).